# Creating consensus from multiple methods of measuring the same entity with some missing values

Tags: missing-data, dimensionality-reduction, measurement

Imagine we have *C* cars and *D* drivers, and each driver takes a large subset of these *C* cars in order to test the rate of fuel consumption for some fixed amount of fuel (let's assume that the number of cars not tested by any given reviewer is relatively small, e.g. <20%).

Every driver has their own preferred way of testing, which means that given the same car each driver will get different consumption rates. For example, perhaps Driver 1 takes the cars down a highway as fast as possible, Driver 2 drives through an inner-city route with the headlights on, Driver 3 just sits in the car and turns the air-con to full power, and so on. So we end up with a matrix of fuel consumption values **F** of size *C* x *D* with some missing values, and even though the values in each row measure the same underlying notion, there may be a large amount of variation because the testing methods are different.

My question is: how can we use this information covering a variety of usage types - but also with missing data - to find a general consensus about which car has best/worst fuel consumption?

Comment: Sounds like *driver* could be a random effect in a mixed effects model

Comment: you could try to determine clusters for drivers, and in each group of drivers have a ranking of vehicules

Comment: @Glen_b that seems like a possibility, but will it be able to handle the missing values?

Comment: Sure, designs don't have to be balanced in regression type models - this would work just as a fixed effects model would. Of course, you'd have to reformat the data but that should be straightforward. Indeed, if you don't need to treat driver as a random effect, you just do it with regression (or unbalanced anova); driver and car are factors.